# Stop onblur event when click on a specified div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following setup:

An input with an onblur event:

```
   <input type="text" onblur="doSomethingCool();" />
```

1 Divs with onclick event:

```
   <div id="divOne" onclick="ipiicaei();"></div>
```

A whole bunch of other html.

I need to stop doSomethingCool() function when clicking on the divOne element. So basically, stop onblur, when clicking in a specified page part.

Note 1: event.stopPropagation doesn't seem to work.

Note 2: The situation has been simplified, questions like: "why do that?", "what's the use?", "why not change the functions so the onclick handles what you need?", "why not change onblur event with something else?" are useless.

Note 3: Already have a solution involving a more or less "global" flag... but personally I feel it is kind of lame, and I'm looking for a better one.

Comment: The problem with the flag is that events are triggered async (or at least it seams so (?) - I may be wrong). Not being sure events are sync (in whatever order), makes the flag seem unreliable.

Comment: @AlexGill: it seems the onblur() is called before the onclick(), so it won't work to unbind the onblur() in onclick()

Answer (score 1):

You could just delayed blur event using:

```
<input type="text" onblur="setTimeout(doSomethingCool);" />
<div id="divOne" onclick="ipiicaei();" tabindex="-1">test</div>
```

See tabindex attribute for `#divOne` letting it being focused.

In CSS, you could add:

```
#divOne {
    outline:none;
}
```

And then, filter onblur event like this:

```
function doSomethingCool(){
   if(document.activeElement.id === "divOne") return;   
   /* any other relevant stuff here */
}
```

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aw7HS/)